# git - removing rails development log

Tags: git

I keep getting the changes made to my development.log in my git repository.  My .gitignore file has:

```
log/*.log
tmp/**/*
doc/api
doc/app
```

So I need two things to happen.

1. Get the development.log file out of my current commit (its now too big for the server to receive)
2. Make sure that it doesn't get back in there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$ git rm log/development.log
$ git commit -m"log too big for the server to receive"
```

An ignorefile won't ignore files that are in the repo, so once development.log is removed everything should work as you expected.

Comment: Removing the log file, still makes a huge delta because it records all the individual lines removed.  So it still doesn't get to the server :(

Comment: How big is this file exactly? I don't know of another way to remove a file but not record that it's been removed. Do you get an error about not being able to recieve? If so, can we see that error? or are you just on a small connection and it's taking a very long time?

Comment: Its an error coming back from dreamhost saying that the git-unpack is taking up too much memory and so its been cancelled.

Comment: you could always try running 'git gc' on both your end and the server end. You might want to start another question that will rescue you from the out of memory problem caused by git!

Answer (score 2):

you can stop tracking the file using 'git rm --cache '

take a look at gitref for details